# How can I achieve this kind of animation using css or js?

Tags: html, css, animation, sass, css-animations

I'm trying to achieve this kind of animation where the items keep going right and then comes from behind:

[image]

But my code doesn't work, it just comes back left at a wrong time and wrong place this is my code:

```css
.floatingItem {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: moveRight 2s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 100ms all ease-in;
  img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 110px;
    transition: 100ms all ease-in;
  }
}

.fi2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@keyframes moveRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="floatingItems">

  <div class="floatingItem">

    <img class="floatImage" src="itemImage" alt="">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your `.jpg` image very nicely shows us how you want your animation to look like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use CSS animations to move an element from left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549238/how-can-i-use-css-animations-to-move-an-element-from-left-to-right)

Comment: How you manage this depends on exactly what effect you want. Do you want to size the icons so that they, plus the gaps between, always at least fill the width of the viewport? (to give the look in the same proportions gap to icon-width as in your image - but with some minimum size??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given layout of overlapping hexagons assumes that there are enough to at least cover the width of the viewport.

Here we assume that enough icons or copies have been put into a line to ensure the width is covered.

While it is possible to animate every icon individually it's quite messy, and can consume more CPU/GPU than a single animation and there is a danger (though slight) that timings could get a bit out of step.

Instead here we group the icons together with a complete copy to form a line. That way we can get continuous scrolling.

CSS variables are used to set widths and margins calculated relatively so that the whole can be made responsive, with upper and lower bounds on the sizes of the icons so they remain readable but don't take over too much of the screen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icons {
  --w: clamp(50px, 10vmin, 100px); /* don't let the icons get too big or too small */
  --n: 15; /* number of icons in each group (a group plus a copy of the group form a line) */
  --m: calc(var(--w) / 20); /* margin on each icon */
  /* for a totally general solution when there aren't many icons would need to adjust margin on each icon so one group at least fills width of viewport */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: scroll 20s infinite linear;
  position: relative;
  --y: 0%;
}
.line:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc((var(--w) / -2) - var(--m)); /* offset the second line */
  --y: -25%;
}
.icon {
  width: var(--w);
  height: auto;
  margin: var(--m);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(var(--y));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(var(--y));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="line">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
    <!-- this is a copy of the group above -->
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
  </div>
  <div class="line">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">

    <!-- this is a copy of the group above -->
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzsQv.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwFZ.png.png">
      <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lIe.png.png">

  </div>
</div>
```

Note: it appears that at least some browsers have problems with calculated values used for top positioning so the bottom line is translated upwards instead of top being set (to make the hexagons 'nestle' into the first line)

Answer (score 0):

> animation where the items keep going right and then comes from behind

This is a moving banner effect. `translate` applies to the dimensions of the element itself, so in your case it'll only move to right equal to it's own width and then jump back to it's original position, it won't keep going till the end of it's parent.

To make a banner effect, you can absolute position the element and animate it's `right` property, which is relative to the parent:

```css
.floatingItems {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.floatingItem {
  position: absolute; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: moveRight 2s linear infinite;
  background: #fff;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
}

@keyframes moveRight {
  0% {
    right: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="floatingItems">
  <div class="floatingItem">
    <img class="floatImage" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```