# css animation move to left, reappear on right and continue to left

Tags: css, css-animations

How do I make the blue platform look like its going to the left, reappears on the right and continues going left? To me, It's kind of tricky because it starts from the left, if it starts from the right than that would be easier.

[image]

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#inner{
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:hidden
}
#platform{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  background: blue;
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move{
  0%{
    left:0px;
  }
  50%{
    left:-200px;
  }
  70%{
    right:200px;
  }
  100%{
  left:0%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="platform"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Isn't that what you did? Please be more clear about your problem.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65549414/8620333 .. it's the opposite direction but simply change left with right and remove the negative sign from the translation

Comment: @TemaniAfif i changed it to right and remove the negative. still doesnt work

Comment: try using reverse: https://jsfiddle.net/t97Ljynu/

Comment: yes, the motion is correct. but i want the starting point to be on the left. right now its on the right.  @TemaniAfif

Comment: but it's an infinite motion? at the end it's going from right to left, the starting point doesn't really matter

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes its infinite, but thats the problem Im trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like below:

```css
#inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

#platform {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(100%);
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    right: 100%;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
  <div id="platform"></div>
</div>
```

Control the delay to start from the left:

```css
#inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

#platform {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(100%);
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  animation: move 2s linear infinite -1.5s;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    right: 100%;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
  <div id="platform"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty crude, but you get the idea:

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/164585fcf077f8cefaef6d0f4fbd9dad

```css
body {
  padding: 60px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-animation: box 2s linear infinite;
          animation: box 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes box {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(500px);
  }
}

@keyframes box {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(500px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```